# MP4 video loads fine in all browsers except from Safari

Tags: html, safari, html5-video

My mp4 videos are not loading in safari for some reason, in every other browser the html5 player works absolutely fine, but in safari it doesn't. This is for a clients website i'm helping with.

I must stress, i cant host these videos on a different server or video hosting platform. does anyone know how i can this to work.

http://superflyanimalphysio.co.uk/course-videos/Caveltti%20Intro.mp4

my code for the player :

```
<video class="eltdf-self-hosted-video" controls="true" preload="auto">
                    <source type="video/mp4" src="http://superflyanimalphysio.co.uk/course-videos/Caveltti%20Intro.mp4"> 

                    </video>
```

Answer (score 1):

You server appears to be not set up to handle range requests properly.

Some browsers will ignore this and simply handle the full video being downloaded, but Safari seems to not play the video in this case - unfortunately the error message in the console is not that helpful.

You can check this by doing a range request test - Apple explain the approach here:

- https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingVideoforSafarioniPhone/CreatingVideoforSafarioniPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006514-SW6

> If the tool reports that it downloaded 100 bytes, the media server correctly handled the byte-range request. If it downloads the entire file, you may need to update the media server.

Doing this for your video confirms that the server is downloading the full video rather than just the range requested:

[image]

It may be worth contacting your hosting provider to ask them to correct the server configuration.